# How would I go about moving an image into a space that isn't related to a div tag or anything using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm doing some web development, and require some help regarding the placement & location of an image beside a paragraph.

[this is how it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zwbp.png)

```css
.img-2yb {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-2yb" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="img beside ig">
```

On the left of the image is whitespace.

My goal is to make the picture right beside the paragraph, not impacting the paragraph. like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kPt1.png)

This is on a laptop view and ipad view. I got the mobile view down, which is why I really hope to find a way that doesn't affect my mobile view somehow.
Also , IK that float is not good to use, which is why hopefulyl I can find some answers in flexbbox.

Thank you all for any  advice :)

Comment: Please update the snippet I created to show the problem. We see no paragraph.

Comment: What you're really asking for here is a basic two-column layout. Resources abound for that.

Comment: @isherwood yeah you're right i followed that approach after a bit of googling. ty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have the image in its own spot next to the content:

```css
.article {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-holder { 
  width: 25%;
}

.article-content {
  width: 70%;
}

.img-2yb {
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="article">

<div class="image-holder">
  <img class="img-2yb" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="img beside ig">
</div>

<div class="article-content">
  <h1>Article Title</h1>
  <h2>Article Subtitle</h2>
  <h3>Author</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

</section>
```

Comment: just a follow up question but; which css code controls the left & right placement of the images? I'm asking because I have two images with the same css code, but their location on the x axis varies slightly. One is just a little bit to the left. I've tried playing with the padding of the different paragraphs, headers and all of that but they don't impact the location of the img. they seem to not want to move at all. I checked with inspect element if they had space to move, and there was tons of space to move - indicated by a purple shade covering the area the image can move in. :)

Comment: A combination of the width proportion (25%, 75%) and the justification rule. You should post a new question with that example.

Comment: sounds good ill post a new question. Thx for the help!